# Erro ao executar .JAR "nenhum atributo de manifesto principal em nutriclinweb-api.jar"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jar

Estou usando o intellij (projeto Spring), fiz os passos corretos para gerar o .jar, tentei de várias formas. Segue o pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>br.unifil.dc</groupId>
<artifactId>nutriclinweb-api</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>nutriclinweb-api</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- mysql -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Migracoes - Flyway -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
        <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate Java 8 Support -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-java8</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Suporte do Jackson para as datas do Java 8 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>br.unifil.dc.nutriclinwebapi.NutriclinwebApiApplication</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Sua classe NutriclinwebApiApplication possui a anotação @SpringBootApplication ?

Comment: Sim, possui....

Answer (score 4):

Você está misturando plugins para geração do seu JAR, você deve utilizar apenas o plugin do Spring Boot para geração do executável.

A geração do JAR executável se dá através da execução `repackage`:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
  <configuration>
    <mainClass>br.unifil.dc.nutriclinwebapi.NutriclinwebApiApplication</mainClass>
    <layout>JAR</layout>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>repackage</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Remova o seu plugin `maven-jar-plugin`, a geração deve ser realizada através do `spring-boot-maven-plugin` apenas.

Se você descompactar o JAR do Spring Boot verá que a estrutura dele é completamente diferente de um JAR normal, por isso devem haver estes cuidados.

Mais informações de configuração do plugin podem ser encontradas na [documentação](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/usage.html)

Comment: Fiz as alterações, gerei o jar novamente e continua com o mesmo erro.

Answer (score -1):

Executei o comando mvn package na raiz do projeto e o .jar foi gerado em target/nome-do-seu-projeto-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar